# How to load a Mapfragment after a button click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am having a MainActivity extending ActionBarAcitivity referencing main_screen_layout.xml

It also has a drawer and a actionbar in it.
I have a button in this activity. I want to load a Map after I click this button.

For the map, I have a mapfragment.xml which contains

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
</fragment>
```

and class Mapfragment.java extending Fragment referencing mapfragment.xml
Mapfragment.java has onCreateView method implemented.

Now I am adding this fragment to the mainactivity at the runtime. That is working fine.
But how do I manipulate the map which is inside the fragment from my activity ?

Comment: why dont you implement your Mapfragment and make it visible / invisible when the button is clicked?, it would be easier

Comment: But that will still load the map. I want to load at the map after the button click.

Answer (score 0):

1. get the fragment that attached on the activity
2. E.G. Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById/Tag(id/tag);
3. get the root view of the fragment
4. E.G. View root = frag.getView();
5. find ur target view to manipulate it, just as in a activity.
6. E.G. View target = root.findViewById(id);

Comment: I am using SupportFragmentManager. And I get null when I am trying to retrieve the fragment from my activity.

Answer (score 0):

The more easy way is using mapView.

put in your fragment xml this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

and in your java fragment class:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mapId); //get view

GoogleMap map = mapView.getMap(); //working with map

mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //to make disappear map
mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // to make appear map
```

Comment: Changing Visibility will still load the map. It will just not show it. I want to load the map after i click the button.

Comment: if you put the property "android:visibility="invisible"" in your xml the map is still loaded?